# How to create a comparison selector and dispatch it correctly?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I already tried to read the official documentation and did not understand it very well.

What I would like to do are two things, which are:

1. Return the person with isMain true;
2. Structure the architecture correctly with the selectors;

I have doubts on how to return this particular person with, and I also have doubts on how to correctly structure the dispatch of this selector in architecture.

**PEOPLE REDUCER:**

```
import { EntityState, EntityAdapter, createEntityAdapter } from '@ngrx/entity';
import { People } from '@shared/interfaces/people.interface';
import * as fromPeopleAction from './people.actions';

export interface State extends EntityState<People> {}
export const adapter: EntityAdapter<People> = createEntityAdapter<People>({
    selectId: (people: People) => people.id,
});

const INIT_STATE: State = adapter.getInitialState({
    data: null,
    error: null,
    loading: false,
});

export function reducer(state = INIT_STATE, action: fromPeopleAction.Actions) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case fromPeopleAction.ActionTypes.CREATE:
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload.people, {
                ...state,
                data: action.payload.people,
                loading: true,
            });
        case fromPeopleAction.ActionTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS:
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload.people, state);
        case fromPeopleAction.ActionTypes.CREATE_FAIL:
            return adapter.addOne(action.payload.people, {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload.error,
                loading: false,
            });
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

**PEOPLE SERVICES**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { People } from '@app/shared/interfaces/people.interface';
import { StoreState } from '@app/store/index';
import * as fromPeopleActions from '@app/store/people/people.actions';
import * as fromPeopleSelectors from '@app/store/people/people.selectors';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class PeopleService {
    people$: Observable<Array<People[]>>;

    constructor(private store: Store<StoreState>) {}

    get(peopleId: string): any {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromPeopleActions.PeopleGet());
    }

    create(people: People): any {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromPeopleActions.PeopleCreate({ people }));
    }

    update(people: Partial<People>): any {
        this.store.dispatch(new fromPeopleActions.PeopleUpdate({ id: people.id, changes: people }));
    }
}
```

**PEOPLE SELECTORES**

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { State, adapter } from './people.reducer';

const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<State>('people');

export const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors(featureSelector);

export const getMainPeople = createSelector(featureSelector, (state: State) => {
    state.ids.forEach((id: any) => {
        if (state.entities[id].isMain) {
            return state.entities;
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did it almost right, you need to return the found person not inside of the `forEach` but in the callback itself.

```js
export const getMainPeople = createSelector(featureSelector, (state: State) => {
    for (const id of state.ids) {
        if (state.entities[id].isMain) {
            return state.entities[id]; // <- don't forget to add id.
        }
    }
});
```